# How to find a start date & end date of any given year & month

Tags: php

I have problem in php find start date & end date of month & year , when i know the year and month ?

ex:

```
input - > year = 2011 , month = 08
output -> start date = 01 , end date = 31
```

Comment: Thirty days has September, April, June, and November. All the rest have thirty-one, except February because it's a rebel.

Comment: Well, in general (I know nothing about PHP), one way to do it is, given any month and any year, initialize a date with GivenMonth+1,01,GivenYear (Month,Day,Year) and then use some sort of Date routine (I'm sure there are plenty in PHP) to subtract 1 day from previously initialized date. This will give you the last day of the month you are looking for. Follow?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
echo date('m-01-Y 00:00:00',strtotime('this month')) . '<br/>';
echo date('m-t-Y 12:59:59',strtotime('this month')) . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Should not it be 11:59:59 instead of 12:59:59 in the last date of a month?

Comment: I think it should be 23:59:59 instead of 12:59:59

Answer (score 8):

Start date will always be 1 and you can find the end date with the following function.

```
cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
```

[reference:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

> cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year ) : int

Comment: I believe the 't' flag for `date()` uses `cal_days_in_month()`, but you method is shorter than mine. +1

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I've never used the 't' flag. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: nice and short - kinda like it :)

Answer (score 4):

Use date (t format gives days in year) and create a time for it:

```
$year = 2011; $month = 6;

$starts = 1;
$ends = date('t', strtotime($month.'/'.$year)); //Returns days in month 6/2011
```

Answer (score 3):

i really can't understand you clearly but to get the start date here is the code

```
date('Y-m-d');
```

this code above will get you the day of today
and to get the end of the running month this code i used before

```
date(’Y-m-d’,strtotime(’-1 second’,strtotime(’+1 month’,strtotime(date(’m').’/01/’.date(’Y').’ 00:00:00′))));
```

i hope this help you in your issue

Answer (score 2):

hi  Try this way u can do it

```
function firstOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
}

function lastOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
}

$date_start = firstOfMonth();
$date_end  = lastOfMonth();`
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into strtotime:

```
echo date("D, M j, Y", strtotime("FIRST DAY OF MAY 2012"));
// Tue, May 1, 2012
echo date("D, M j, Y", strtotime("last DAY june 2012")); // gotcha! using June.
// Thu, May 31, 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP may have a more elegant way of doing this, but if you want a generic algorithm, here's what you need to do...

All months other than February have a fixed number of days. February has 29 only when it's a leap year. Here are the rules to check if it's a leap year:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
4. The year is a leap year (February has 29 days).
5. The year is not a leap year (February has 28 days).

Answer (score -1):

```
$year = '2017';
$month = '05';
echo date("$year-$month-01");
echo "<br>";
echo date("$year-$month-t");
```

shortest solution in my own opinion.