# Get which day of the week the month starts on for given input

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a function which defines what day of the week the month starts on for the current month:

```
public function firstDayOfMonth()
    {
        $day =  (int) date("w", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
        return $day;
    }
```

How would I alter the above, in a way that allows me to get the day of the week the month starts on if I give it input, for example 'June'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a start date & end date of any given year & month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184953/how-to-find-a-start-date-end-date-of-any-given-year-month) - Please use this site search, there are tons of data questions, most of them answered correctly. I doubt your scenario hasn't been handled out there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function firstDayOfMonth($month) {
    $day =  (int) date("w", strtotime($month . ' 01,' . date('Y') . ' 00:00:00'));
    return $day;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
$month = 'June';
$day = (int) date('w', strtotime($month));
```

Comment: well in that case: $month = 'june 2012';