# How to pass last month in where condition in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to fetch records of last month and last week from my database.

I have login and logout data in database also i have filed called date_data which is the date.

Now i am fetching my data by this:

```
public function monthly_login($emp_id = NULL)
{

      $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');

      $this->db->select('*');

      $this->db->from('daily_data2');

      //$this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', date('1-m'));

      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);

      $this->db->where('entry >','100');

      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");

      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');

      $query = $this->db->get();



       $res   = $query->result();        

      return $res;

 }
```

I dont know what should i pass in my where condition so that i get last month and last week's data

Comment: Do you want both last month and last week data or do you want only last week data of last month?

Comment: No i want last month data i.e December and last week of current month

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya i will write another method for week but what about the where condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->where("date_data BETWEEN {$startDate} AND {$endDate} ");
```

Here $startDate and $endDate you can Calculate via php's date and strtotime function as follows

For last 7 days

```
 $startDate = date('y-m-d',strtotime("-1 week"), "\n";)
 $endDate   = date('y-m-d',strtotime("now"), "\n";)
```

For last 30 days

```
 $startDate = date('y-m-d',strtotime("-30 days"), "\n";)
 $endDate   = date('y-m-d',strtotime("now"), "\n";)
```

So you can use in this way

As For your Requirement based on your comment that you want the data of last month regardless of the current date in that case you have to calculate the date range as follows

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
$startDate->modify( 'first day of last month' );

$endDate   = new DateTime();
$endDate->modify( 'last day of last month' );
```

In case you are using DateTime object in that case you have to update your Query like this.

```
$this->db->where("date_data BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");
```

Comment: but i want just the last month data i dont want to use between function here

Comment: you mean to say that you what data of last month not exactly the last 30 days data correct ? so regards less of you are accessing the data on 5 th of jan or 31 of Jan you want data of Dec month only Correct ?

Comment: in that case you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184953/how-to-find-a-start-date-end-date-of-any-given-year-month and use "last month" inside now function that should work

Comment: what is $start and $end data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99811/discussion-between-anand-thakkar-and-rajan).

Answer (score 3):

try this...

**For Week :**

```
$this->db->where('date_data <=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS )');
```

**For Month :**

```
$this->db->where('date_data <=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAYS )');
```

**For Last Month start from 1st date**

```
$this->db->where('date_data <=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAYS,"%Y-%m-01")');
```

Try Either of below:

```
$this->db->where('date_data <=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%Y-%m-01")');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('timestamp >=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%Y-%m-01")');
```

Comment: always there for help. if worked then Don't forget to mark.

Comment: Yeah sure let me just cross check and i will do it for sure

Comment: hey should not it be DATE_SUB??

Comment: because it shows data from november also i just want last month data not all data

Comment: what should i do for last month's data

Comment: means this is january then you want data only of December..?

Comment: PLease Help me to get data on basis on last month if there are 31 days then 1st to 31st or else 30th